# How to automatically trigger action in Struts2 when user access root of webapp?

Tags: java, struts2

I build simple web application StrutsCrud.
To access its welcome page user can type:

```
http://localhost:8080/StrutsCrud/
```

I want to automatically trigger action when user types such url.

So, how to assign struts action in struts.xml to such url(root of webapp) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way of doing it in Struts. 
`Follow this procedure, it works without an issue and mostly it's the standard way`

in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and in index.jsp

```
<jsp:forward page="/yourDefault.action" />
```